# 20.04: Adjust display brightness in smaller steps with brightness buttons

Tags: laptop, brightness, backlight

The buttons work (out of the box) and brightness is preserved (with `acpi_backlight=vendor` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` and `sudo update-grub`).

Brightness is controlled between 0 and 255 by ±1 (by `echo`ing to `/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness`), but buttons change it only by ±12, which is very coarse to my eyes. Ideally, I'd like to have a logarithmic scale or, at least, to make it change by ±1.

I expect to find some configuration file to set the step or all the levels manually.

I'm aware of `xbacklight` and, perhaps, it could work, but I believe there's a native way without any additional software.

Answer (score 1):

I must disappoint you because I cannot provide a native way without additional software. Just indicating how I implement brightness keys with a smaller incremental change.

I use the utility `light`, which in recent versions of Ubuntu can be installed with the command `sudo apt install light`. Otherwise, it can be installed from the [github page](https://github.com/haikarainen/light/releases/) of the author.

The command `light -A 1` will increase brightness by 1%, `light -U 1` will decrease brighness. I bound these commands to the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Brightness Up/Down</kbd>. The utility allows to define a minimum brightness, so you never blackout your screen.